# Keycloak access token works on multiple instances

Tags: keycloak

as the title briefly describes, I have multiple instances of my application, each having their respective microservices running in k8s, including Keycloak.
My issue is that if i login to the instance A, i can take the access token and use it to make requests to instance B of my application.
I was wondering what settings do i need to change? I have a frontend client without set up like in the picture bellow setup in each Keycloak instance.
[image]

I am thinking that it has something to do with client secrets or whatever Keycloak uses to sign the token, since they are identical (through k8s deployment definition files) but i cannot manage to fix this issue.